# Save JSON documents on couchdb from javascript using kanso

Tags: javascript, json, couchdb, kanso

How can a JSON document be saved on couchdb using "db" package in kanso through your javascript code?
This is what I've tried but it doesn't work:

```
var db=require('db').use('it');
db.saveDoc(doc, function(err,response) {
    if(err) {
        alert('Error');
    } else {
        alert('Data Added successfully');
    }
});
```

Comment: Do you get an error in the console? You can check if you can access the db from the browser. Try to run this: var db = require('db').use('it'); db.info(function(err, res){ console.log(res); }) You should get an object resembling this: {db_name: "it", doc_count: 5, doc_del_count: 20, update_seq: 1124, purge_seq: 0…}

Comment: Please add information to your question: which errors do you get back? Is the doc you are passing in correct json format? Which is the output?